# How can I decode a json File using base64 decode?

Tags: python, json, ubuntu, base64, jq

I have a json file and I have to extract only the value of the key "data" and decode the base64-encoded.

This is the json file

```
{
    "equno": "229151246954324320",
    "data": "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"
}
```

I tried using jq

```
 jq -r '.[].data' < test.json | base64 --decode
```

But I got this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot index string with string "data"
```

I have no idea how to resolve this error. I also tried using python but I couldn't decode it.
Help me, please!

Comment: The `[]` is wrong, you don't have an array here.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it by  'jq -r '.data' < test.json | base64 --decode' and I got this.
 �
         �M��x�Ȟ�tE�F�
*�=��o�E�t���h�N�jE�}�u�?�)���f���(;��7�_����l!�M'���Bȇ�-b��=5���4�� }���M�`liW炭QL�G! ....
Maybe the data is not in base64?

Comment: That *is* the decoded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you have loaded the json data into an object. You can then try the following:

```
import json
import base64

json_obj = {
    "equno": "229151246954324320",
    "data": "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"
}

print(base64.b64decode(json_obj["data"]))
```

Comment: I did that and I got this result:
b'\t\xdc\x0b\xefM\xe6\xeax\xe3\xc8\x9e\xedtE\xddF\x86\n*\xfe=\xa1\xabo\xf5E\xaft\xb3\x8d\xa5h\x1d\xe3N\xdfjE\xcd}\xbbu\xf2?\xaa)\xbf\xed\xa1\x88\x07f\xf8\xf7\xe2(;\x8a\xee\x177\xb0_\xae\xa4\xdf\x ...

Comment: So maybe the value is not in base64?

Comment: @HugoZárate Is the provided data key value encoded in base 64 originally that we are trying to decode?

Comment: Again, that *is* the data you wanted to decode. If it was plain text, why would it need to be base64-encoded?

Comment: @HugoZárate The key "data" value is in valid base-64, you can verify it on this link: https://base64.guru/tools/validator.
You may also decode it using: https://base64.guru/converter/decode

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that in Python:

```
import base64
import json
with open("sample_data.json") as f: 
    text = f.read()
    d = json.loads(text)
    data = base64.b64decode(d["data"])
```

The variable `data` now contains the decoded content of the relevant item in the json file.

Answer (score 0):

If the string in .data were a valid base64 encoding of a UTF-8 string, the following would be equivalent:

```
jq -r .data input.json | base64 -D
```

and

```
jq -r '.data|@base64d' input.json
```

As it happens, with the given JSON, `base64` shows there is a problem:

```
$ jq -r .data input.json | base64 -D
Invalid character in input stream.
```